# Listar todas las tablas de una base de datos en MySQL

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, mariadb

Quiero saber el nombre de mis tablas de una base de datos para así poder ver después el tamaño de las tablas y los registros de estas.

Encontré este comando para citar los nombres de las tablas de una base de datos

```sql
SHOW FULL TABLES
```

Pero no sé como acceder, se accede con *`sudo mysql -u root -p`*, poniendo el nombre de la base de datos en lugar de *root*, o el nombre de usuario de la base de datos en lugar de *root*?.

O pudiera acceder con `sudo mysql -u root -p`, poniendo el nombre de mi usuario de mi base de datos en lugar de *root* y después poner el comando para ver las tablas de la siguiente manera:

```sql
SHOW FULL TABLES FROM [BASE_DATOS]
```

Answer (score 1):

Gracias he podido acceder con mysql -u usuario -p
Aún no encuentro un comando para saber el tamaño de cada registro, pero encontré algunos que ayuda a saber el nombre de cada tabla y también el tamaño, y uno más para saber la cantidad de registros de cada tabla.
Los he encontrado en estos links:
https://www.neoguias.com/tamano-tabla-mysql/
https://www.linuxito.com/programacion/183-como-obtener-la-cantidad-de-registros-de-una-base-de-datos

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con esta consulta `SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables;`. También puedes checar aquí https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8334493/get-table-names-using-select-statement-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

Quizás un poco tarde pero prueba con este `select`. Tiene toda información y más.

```
SELECT table_name, TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, TABLE_TYPE, ENGINE, VERSION
, ROW_FORMAT, TABLE_ROWS, AVG_ROW_LENGTH, DATA_LENGTH, MAX_DATA_LENGTH, INDEX_LENGTH
, DATA_FREE, AUTO_INCREMENT, CREATE_TIME, UPDATE_TIME, CHECK_TIME, TABLE_COLLATION
, CHECKSUM, CREATE_OPTIONS, TABLE_COMMENT 
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_schema = 'tubasededatos'
```

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).